# Scorm 2004 calculating completion percentage based on interactions

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I am using Scorm 2004 and I am wondering if there is a way to calculate completion percentage based on interaction (i.e `cmi.interactions.*`)? or what's the straightforward way to calculate completion percentage?

The reason I was thinking about using interaction is because we have: `cmi.interactions.0.objectives.n.id` and I was thinking we can use `cmi.objective.n.completion_status`. But how to find the total number of objectives to find the completion ratio?

I appreciate any help or hint.

**Update**

I was able to parse `suspended_data`. Now the question is how to get completion progress out of it.

```
{
  "progress": {
    "lessons": {
      "1": {
        "c": 1,
        "p": 100,
        "i": {
          "0": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "1": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "2": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "3": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "4": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "5": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "6": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "7": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "8": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              },
              "1": {
                "c": 1
              },
              "2": {
                "c": 1
              },
              "3": {
                "c": 1
              },
              "4": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "9": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "10": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "11": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "12": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "13": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "14": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "15": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "16": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "2": {
        "c": 1,
        "p": 100,
        "i": {
          "0": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "1": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "2": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "3": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "4": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "5": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "6": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "7": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "8": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "9": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "3": {
        "c": 1,
        "p": 100,
        "i": {
          "0": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "1": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "2": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "3": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "4": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "5": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "6": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "7": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "8": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "9": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "10": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "11": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "12": {
            "c": 1
          },
          "13": {
            "c": 1,
            "i": {
              "0": {
                "c": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "4": {
        "a": 7,
        "p": 47,
        "r": 1,
        "s": 20,
        "i": {
          "0": {
            "c": 1,
            "k": 1,
            "s": 0
          },
          "1": {
            "c": 1,
            "k": 0,
            "s": 1
          },
          "2": {
            "c": 1,
            "k": 0,
            "x": [1]
          },
          "3": {
            "c": 1,
            "k": 1,
            "s": 3
          },
          "4": {
            "c": 1,
            "k": 0,
            "s": 3
          },
          "5": {
            "c": 1,
            "k": 0,
            "s": 2
          },
          "6": {
            "c": 1,
            "k": 1,
            "s": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "p": 75
  },
  "score": 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are looking for the `progress_measure` field, likely in `objectives`.** There are two, one for objective and one for overall sco:

You should be able to use `cmi.objectives.n.progress_measure` to get completion progress for the objective itself. There are some good examples [here in this forum](https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/how-to-manage-cmi-data-model-variables) that may help: https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/how-to-manage-cmi-data-model-variables

**Description from the [documentation](https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/) of the data model**:

> `cmi.objectives.n.progress_measure` (real (10,7) range (0..1), RW)
> Measure of the progress the learner has made toward completing the
> objective

**How to use the data stored in this calculated field to get completion %:**

Notice that the range is from 0 to 1 so to get the completion % you need to multiply the value in `cmi.objectives.n.progress_measure` by 100 to get a percentage (e.g. 0.67 * 100 = 67%).

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? This is the correct answer, at least in terms of where the progress measure is stored in the data model and how to access it. I'll edit to clarify that you'll want to multiply cmi.objectives.n.progress_measure by 100 to get the percentage.